# ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

os: mac os yosemite
python: 2.7.6 --  64-bit
installed: numpy,skipy,matplotlib,nose

I get the following error.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets

$ pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Someone help me please!

Answer (score 5):

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
or export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'path where your installed modules are'

to find out the path where your modules are installed, try to run pip install again and it will output the location

Comment: Hi, you can also see the installation,  by "pip show scipy"

Answer (score 4):

Ran into a similar problem recently and spent too much time googling it while the error was simple: my file was named **sklearn.py** It might be why your import is not working.

Answer (score 2):

When installing on Ubuntu Linux you have to have to install dependencies first using apt-get, then use a pip install otherwise the normal pip install of scikit-learn won't work properly. See below:

**Step 1: Make sure apt-get is updated**

sudo apt-get update

**Step 2: Install dependencies**

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base

**Step 3: pip install Scikit Learn**

pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved just writing:

```
from sklearn import datasets

data = datasets.load_iris()
```

Answer (score 0):

sklearn I was sure that you have installed.
So, after you create a symbolic link the sklearn to Python interpreter, it went well.

```
ln -s 'path of sklearn' 'path of python interpreter'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're running the right Python? It may be that scikit-learn is only installed for Python3, and not Python 2, so you may need to run `python3 my_code.py` instead of just `python my_code.py`.